# What's the correct way to get a list of users in this bash script?

Tags: bash, variables

I have a script that checks each user's home directory for the existence of a maildir and archives old emails accordingly. The way I was doing this is basically this:

```
for USER in $(ls /home)
do
<function to check for maildir and remove old files>
```

I ran my script through `shellcheck` and it gave the the warning

> SC2045 - Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.

If I change my script to use `for USER in /home/*`, it changes the value of $USER:

```
for USER in $(ls /home); do echo $USER ; done;
```

gives:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

But

```
for USER in /home/*; do echo $USER ; done;
```

gives:

```
/home/user1
/home/user2
/home/user3
```

and breaks my script in later places.

If I start doing things like parsing /etc/passwd for usernames I'd then need to check if they have home directories etc so it would make the script more complicated for the sake of following best practice. I couldn't work out a way to `grep -v` out the "/home/" part of the variable values from the second example. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think the problem is that it breaks your script, why is having a full path breaking your script?

Comment: @123 Because I use the variable $USER to check paths for the existence of dirs in their home directories and create user specific temp files containing data. E.g. `find ... > $USER_files.txt`. Like I said in the Q, I could rewrite the whole thing but it doesn't seem like worth it for the sake of one single error in shellcheck when it otherwise all works OK.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you might have user directories located in some directory other than `/home/`? Should you perhaps parse `/etc/passwd`, determine the home directory based on a field in that table?

Comment: @ghoti I know that would be best practice to make it portable, but on my own server there are only home dirs in /home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `glob` loop like this:

```
cd /home

for u in */; do
    echo "${u%/}"
done

cd -
```

`*/` only lists directories.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a fairly simple alternative that wouldn't require loads of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep's Perl mode `grep -P` such as:

```
for USER in /home/*; do 
    echo $USER | grep -Po "(?<=/home/).*"
done
```

The `(?<=/home/)` represents a lookbehind, which will not be considered part of the match, and won't be printed because of the `-o`. This has the advantage of not requiring you to cd to the home directory and back, and besides, `grep -Po` is incredibly useful to know about.

Alternatively using `find` (which is also a very useful program), you can do:

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```